# Error can not close Antd Popover when click outside, using Antd Popover, Form, Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a Form in a Popover. In Form, there is a Select, choose an option, then call form.resetField() method of Antd Form. After that, click to outside of Popover, it throws error and Popover dont't close.

I try to use EventListener to close Popover but not run